# Incremental image backup for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, community-faq-proposed, incremental-backup

I'm looking for a backup program that does incremental backups and that I can use to completely image my main hard drive.

For example I use the `C:\` as my main drive and have `E:\backups` as my backup. I want to be able to have it make incremental backups such that if my computer becomes infested I can just choose an earlier snapshot and restore my entire HDD to that image. I'm also looking for something that had auto scheduling.

Is there any free or open source program that does this for Windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Windows Backup and Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore)** (search `Backup` in the start menu) does a great job. By default it copies your libraries and user profile settings into 200MB zip files along with hashes and creates a VHD (virtual hard disk) as well, which can be used to do a full image restore from the recovery menu of the installation DVD.

It does incremental system images and backups automatically, and can be set to run on a regular schedule. Backups can be made to a local drive on all versions, and Windows 7 Pro, Ultimate and Enterprise can backup to a network location too.

#### Related questions:

- [ntbackup workalike for adhoc full backups in Windows 7 thats free and preferably open source](https://superuser.com/questions/219175/ntbackup-workalike-for-adhoc-full-backups-in-windows-7-thats-free-and-preferably)
- [Software to backup data and files on a Windows computer](https://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows)
- [Can I make my PC backup and then sleep on demand with WHS?](https://superuser.com/questions/17172/can-i-make-my-pc-backup-and-then-sleep-on-demand-with-whs/)
- [Windows 7 Backup - Does the "system image" include all the files on my drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/230095/windows-7-backup-does-the-system-image-include-all-the-files-on-my-drive/)

Comment: Windows Backup in Windows 7 is documented to perform incremental backups.  It does not.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/50f3ff7a-2ae7-41c1-ac92-41edaed1e2f9/windows7-backup-not-doing-incremental?forum=w7itprogeneral  And a smaller quibble:  It can be set to run on a regular schedule but will only do so if the machine is not in sleep mode.