# Best free whole-disc backup tool for Windows 7?

Tags: backup, windows-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incremental Backup which also is imageable](https://superuser.com/questions/226766/incremental-backup-which-also-is-imageable)

I bought and used Norton Ghost on Windows XP. I loved that program, it had the exact functionality I wanted. Since I upgraded to Windows 7, I can no longer use it because it doesn't work on 7. Do not want to buy NG again just because of that. Is there a good, free as in beer alternative?

I am only interested in backing up the whole drive (first drive, C), not so much in backing up individual files and folders. Backing up the whole drive is faster and I have plenty of external space. Backups should be incremental of course. Any recommendations?

Comment: Questions like this have been asked so many times that it's starting to get ridiculous. Use the built-in Windows Image Backup. It's right there under Backup and Restore in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

[Norton Ghost 15](http://antivirus.norton.com/norton/ps/1up_us_en_gh.html?om_sem_cid=hho_sem_sy:us:ggl:en:e%7Ckw0000022378%7C6426226996&om_sem_site=)

[Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp)

[Ping](http://ping.windowsdream.com/)  (boot disc only imaging)

[EASEUS Todo](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I like [G4L (Ghost 4 Linux)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/).  It is free, very similar to Norton Ghost, and is included on [Hirens Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) (which is now completely legit).  Works great with Windows 7.